# Function casting and the internal representation of the function arguments list in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, casting, clang

I was wondering how does a C compiler (I tried gcc and clang) organize the argument list of functions internally. For this purpose I made a program consisting of two files, for instance:

foo.c :

```
double foo (double (*f) (void *, double), void * arg, double x)
{
    return f (arg, x);
}
```

main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double foo (double (*) (double), double);

double bar (double x)
{   
    return x + x;
}

int main ()
{   
    double x = foo (&bar, 2);
    printf ("%g\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

and played with the argument list and the body of the `foo` in the foo.c. When foo.c is not consistent with definitions in the main.c the behavior of the program should be undefined according to the C standard (if I understand correctly?).

I have tried several variants (including the one above), for which the program will print 4.
The one of the more exotic is

```
double foo (double x, double (*f) (char, double, int), int r)
{
    char a;
    return f (a, x, r);
}
```

. However, if I would try something like

```
double foo (double x, double (*f) (char, double, double), double y)
{
    char a;
    return f (a, y, x);
}
```

the result would not be 4, but if I write `f(a, x, y)` instead, I get 4 again.

The experiment makes me think that the argument list is internally represented as a list of arrays corresponding to different types, in which the information about the order of the arguments of different types is lost. For example, the argument list
`(char a, double x, int i, double y, char b)` would be something like `(char:{a, b}, int:{i}, double:{x, y})` and the casting to the `(double z, char c)` would equal `(char:{c = a}, double:{z = x})`, where I have defined `T:{}` as an array of type `T`.

So:

Is my interpretation correct?

Is this behavior standardized somewhere?

How much can I rely on such a behavior?

This behavior allows some generic programming. Does anybody exploit it in practice?

thanks!

Comment: Is this on 64 or 32 bit code? The calling conventions differ between x86 and AMD64 - the former passes arguments right to left on the stack while the latter passes some in [various registers, ordered by type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). It's the linker which patches the code together, and all that does is deal with symbol loading and relocation, not types.

Comment: @MathewHall it is x86_64, thanks for the link.

Comment: @MathewHall +1 Indeed, the x86_64 calling convention on Linux is responsible for the observed behavior. I was in fact "lucky" with the types I have used. Repeating tests by switching double to int is a mess as it should be. Thanks again. If it would be possible I would accept your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely  on any behavior if the signature of the function don't match. Your program can work properly, crash, or launch a rocket missile. This is the definition of undefined behavior.

You can only rely on something if you use variadict functions, or functions for which you don't describe the parameters (i.e. f(), not to be confused with f(void)). For those, there are rules on argument promotion and conversions. Look for C99 standard to know more.

The rest is pure speculation. You can observe and deduce some behavior if you know how the assemblee language of your processor works. For example in x86, the standard ways to call functions and pass parameters are well defined...

Anyway, it's not a good idea to rely on undefined behaviors.